# How to set blue phone links/anchors to another color on iPad/Safari?

Tags: ipad, safari

I've created a site and the phone number on the top of the screen is normally brown through CSS, but when I'm opening it in iPad it becomes blue, I know that there are functonality to call around it, but how can I change it's behavior (just change the color)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this meta to your HEAD tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

But, if you are using Objective-C (loading the HTML on a UIWebView) and want to prevent the phone detection on all pages you can set:

```
_webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Comment: Thank U very much, I'll try it later - seems goot to me

Comment: Yes and no - because I need to keep functionality, but set the other color to the phone. So, how to do this?

Comment: You are using webview or just Safari?

Answer (score 6):

I prefer not to disable the functionality but override the color;

```
a[href^=tel] {
text-decoration:inherit;
color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: That is the correct answer imho. You just want to disable the color, not the whole link